# Jenkins: how to add/update data into rb-matrix with an automation

Tags: jenkins, groovy, automation, ldap, devops

In my organization I'm a Jenkins admin and I manage users coming from an LDAP server (LDAP server is configured correctly within Jenkins). We've set-up an automation to add or update LDAP records when is needed and we can fill our jenkins LDAP groups and subgroups.
We've configured the Matrix Authorization Strategy Plugin to manage users directly on Jenkins but, at today, we can only add manually users to this matrix. I've tried to find if there was a kind of WA to update the configurations.xml file on the container but I think there is not the possibility to accomplish this operation.
Now, is there some plugin/groovy/py/other linux based solutions that can help us to fill the manage-role-matrix and assign-role-matrix not manually but with a kind of script or automation? Thank's anyway to all!

Answer (score 0):

I use organisation folder pipelines, which allows me to set per project access for all project repos include new repo. This is out of box solution

For your goal you need to dig in Job class to set access. You may start from [here](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/role-strategy/com/michelin/cio/hudson/plugins/rolestrategy/RoleMap.html)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sam. Your link is very interesting! Anyway, I found a more scalable solution and I realize my goal using just 2 very simple curls like this:

```
curl -vk -s --user "<user>:<psw>" \
-F "type=globalRoles" \
-F "roleName=${roleName}" \
-F "permissionIds=${permissionIds}" \
-F 'overwrite=true' \
"${JENKINS_URL}/role-strategy/strategy/addRole"
```

With this curl you can add a new role by **roleName** into first (global roles) matrix. If you want to add this role into second matrix you must change **type=globalRoles** into **type=projectRoles** and that's all.
Regarding assign role, the curl is very similar and it's:

```
curl -vk -s --user "<user>:<psw>" \
-F "type=globalRoles" \
-F "roleName=${roleName}" \
-F "sid=${uid}" \
-F "assignedSIDs=${uid}" \
"${JENKINS_URL}/role-strategy/strategy/assignRole"
```

With this second curl you can add a new user by **assignedSIDs=uid** into first and second matrix (always using globalRoles and projectRoles).

Now I need to add a cloud pod template in the same way...I'm sure that there is a similar solution!

Hope this solution can help others! Thanks :)